# JQUERY datetimepicker onSelect is not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker, onselect

I am trying to use the datetimepicker from jquery. I want to clear some input fields whenever you select a new date but my onSelect doesn't really work. 
First off, it fires only once on document loadup. After that it never fires again.
Second, the onSelect do not work with anonymous functions.

**This do not work**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function () {
    $('#dateValue').datetimepicker({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      onSelect: function() {
        console.log("testing");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**This do work but fires only on document load, then never again**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function () {
    $('#dateValue').datetimepicker({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      onSelect: console.log("testing")
    });
  });
});
```

**The imported files in my head tag in index.html**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>....</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="myCSS.css">
</head>
```

**EDIT: I goofed and forgot to give the error message**

```
Uncaught TypeError: option onSelect is not recognized!
    at Function.<anonymous> (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:8)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.l.options (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:8)
    at c (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:9)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:9)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.a.fn.datetimepicker (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:9)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:3)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: onSelect is from jQuery UI Datepicker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [`dp.change`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange) event which fired when the date is changed.

```js
$('#dateValue').datetimepicker({
  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
});

$("#dateValue").on("dp.change", function() {
  console.log("testing");
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class='input-group date' id='dateValue'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try on statement

```
$("#dateValue").on("onselect",function(){ console.log("testing"); });
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score -1):

You are using Bootstrap `datetimepicker` component.The `onselect` event is not part of that.

You have to use

```
$("#dateValue").on("dp.change", function (e) {
//your code
});
```